# Recursive excel manipulation using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and VB.net and I have 2 folders.
1. C:\phd\unclean
2. C:\phd\clean

In the unclean folder.  I have a variety of subfolders and subsubfolders containing various files.  I want to take all .csv files in all of unclean's subfolders and subsubfolders, process them to clean them, and output them into C:\clean BUT with the same sub folder structure as was found in unclean.

Here is my code so far...

```
    Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.IO
Class MainWindow
    Dim xl As Excel.Application = New Excel.ApplicationClass()
    Dim wb, wbTraj, wbForce As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws, wsData, wsLeg As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim trajEndRow, analogEndRow, analogDataRow, forceLegRowStart, forceLegRowEnd, forceDataRow, lastDataRow As Integer
    Dim cell, trajDataRangeSrc, trajDataRangeDest, trajLegSrc, trajLegDest, analogDataRange, forceDataRangeSrc, forceDataRangeDest, forceLegSrc, forceLegDest As Excel.Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim blank As String
    Dim iIndex As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String

    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
        If cleanRadioButton.IsChecked = True Then
            Dim list As List(Of String) = GetFilesRecursive("C:\phd\unclean")

            ' Loop through and display each path.
            For Each path In list
                clean(path)
            Next

        Else inputRadioButton.IsChecked = True
            ' do something else
        End If
        releaseObject(ws)
        releaseObject(wsData)
        releaseObject(wsLeg)
        releaseObject(wb)
        releaseObject(wbForce)
        releaseObject(wbTraj)
        releaseObject(xl)
    End Sub

Public Shared Function GetFilesRecursive(ByVal initial As String) As List(Of String)
        ' This list stores the results.
        Dim result As New List(Of String)

        ' This stack stores the directories to process.
        Dim stack As New Stack(Of String)

        ' Add the initial directory
        stack.Push(initial)

        ' Continue processing for each stacked directory
        Do While (stack.Count > 0)
            ' Get top directory string
            Dim dir As String = stack.Pop
            Try
                ' Add all immediate file paths
                result.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.csv"))

                ' Loop through all subdirectories and add them to the stack.
                Dim directoryName As String
                For Each directoryName In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
                    stack.Push(directoryName)
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Loop

        ' Return the list
        Return result
    End Function

Private Sub clean(path)
        strPath = path
        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)

            'Loop through the sheets.
            For iIndex = 1 To xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                ws = xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(iIndex)

                'Loop through the columns.
                For iCol = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                    'Check row 10 of this column for the char of *
                    If InStr(ws.Cells(10, iCol).Value, "*") > 0 Then
                        'We have found a column with the char of *
                        xl.DisplayAlerts = False
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        ws.Columns(iCol).EntireColumn.Delete
                        iCol = iCol - 3
                    End If
                Next iCol

            Next iIndex
            wb.SaveAs(Filename:="C:\phd\clean\" & wb.Name, FileFormat:=51)
            wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            strFile = Dir()
        Loop
        MessageBox.Show("The csv files have now been cleaned.  Congrats.")
    End Sub
```

However I can't get it to work and i'm getting myself lost.  Can anyone help with me going through a structure, finding any .csv file, cleaning it and then outputting it in same file structure under clean folder and continuing the search for next .csv file??

boggling my mind...

thx

Comment: Have you tested each part separately? You should start by looking if the files are properly in your list, than just copy them to their new location and after that is well tested, you add the cleaning code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving the directory name alone doesnt seem to be enough if you want to clone the folder structure.  You also need to know which CSVs were in each folder.  For that, I would save a `List(Of FileInfo)` which will include both the CSV file name and its original folder.  To collect them:

```
Private myCSVList As List(Of FileInfo)

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, 
      e As EventArgs) Handles Button29.Click
    myCSVList = New List(Of FileInfo)

    FindCSVs("C:\Temp")
    ' print some:
    For n As Int32 = 0 To myCSVList.Count - 1 Step 2
        Console.WriteLine(myCSVList(n).FullName)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub FindCSVs(path As String)
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    ' add the csvs in THIS folder
    myCSVList.AddRange(di.EnumerateFiles("*.csv").ToArray)

    ' look for csvs in sub folders
    For Each d As DirectoryInfo In di.EnumerateDirectories
        FindCSVs(d.FullName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

> C:\Temp\capitals.csv
>   C:\Temp\mycsv.csv
>   C:\Temp\townsinfo.csv
>   C:\Temp\A\AA\capitals.csv
>   C:\Temp\A\AA\AAA\AAAA\capitals.csv
>   C:\Temp\B\BB\capitals.csv

Now that you have a ToDo list of all the CSVs, process them and write them back out to the new folder.  You should be able to use `String.Replace` on the stored path to change `C:\phd\unclean` to `C:\phd\clean`. I'd include the drive portion to change just the first appearance in case "clean" appears elsewhere in the path.

In cases where you need to do something a bit more extensive for the initial list, exclude some based on the date or name etc, I might use another `Sub`:

```
...
' add the csvs in this folder
myCSVList.AddRange(LoadFiles(di))

Private Function LoadFiles(di As DirectoryInfo) As FileInfo()
    Dim thisFolder = di.EnumerateFiles("*.csv").ToList
    ' ...do stuff to remove unqualified ones
    ' ...
    Return thisFolder.ToArray

End Function
```